# How to include code attribute in parse_arg?

Tags: python, argparse

I have the following code:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Gobblet game")
parser.add_argument("code", metavar = "CODE", type=str, help= "Player code")
parser.add_argument("-l", "--lister", action="store_true", help= "Lists existing games")
attrib = parser.parse_args()
```

When I do print(attrib), an error prompt tells me that the the CODE argument is required. Where does this argument need to be placed in my code for this to create a Namespace of the player's code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've added mandatory positional argument to your code with this line:

```
parser.add_argument("code", metavar = "CODE", type=str, help= "Player code")
```

That means your script needs to be called with at least one non-option argument. That is, if your script is called `myscript.py`, you would need to call it like this:

```
python myscript.py <player_code_goes_here>
```

Or:

```
python myscript.py --lister <player_code_goes_here>
```

If you call `parser.parse_args()` and your command line doesn't have a non-option argument, it will fail as you've described.

If you intended `code` to be an option (like `--code`), you would need:

```
parser.add_argument("--code", metavar = "CODE", type=str, help= "Player code")
```